# Know the bluetooth address of fire tv stick remote connected to firetv

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, adb, amazon-fire-tv

I am trying to figure out the bluetooth address of my firetv stick remote. 
I have adb access enabled and can access firetv stick.

Is there a command to find out the paired / connected devices on my firetv stick ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought the FireTV remote was WiFi, not Bluetooth. If I do `adb shell dumpsys bluetooth_manager` I don't see a remote, but `adb shell dumpsys input` shows me the remote attached

Comment: the remote works over bluetooth, fire stick has both - bluetooth and wifi capabilities. I will try the comman.

Answer (score 0):

If it were me I would purchase one of [these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007R9UPHA) or [these](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2269). The BT Sniffer works with windows and wireshark and from what I gather is a little easier to use than ubertooth.

Ubertooth documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/ubertooth/wiki), and requires linux to operate and also works with wireshark. It's not that bad, just takes a little time if you've never used linux before.

Using Ubertooth with Wireshark sniffs out BLE advertising packets exposing the MAC address, as seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOFT8.png). What you're looking for is the 4th line, Advertising Address. This was a packet of sensor I bought.

Other than that, I'm not sure of any other way to discover a BT MAC address.